# Sendmail error. NOQUEUE: SYSERR()

Tags: sendmail

Sendmail daemon is spamming with these kind of messages:

`Jul 7 18:00:00 localhost sendmail[9027]: NOQUEUE: SYSERR(pgsql): /etc/mail/sendmail.cf: line 0: cannot open: Permission denied`

Permissions of `/etc/mail/sendmail.cf` are:

`[root@localhost ~]# ls -al /etc/mail/sendmail.cf`

`-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  58285 Jan  4  2013 /etc/mail/sendmail.cf`

Permissions of `/etc/mail` directory are:

`[root@localhost ~]# ls -al /etc/mail`

`total 504`

`drwxr-xr--   2 root  wheel    512 Jan  4  2013 .`

In system there is `pgsql` user, so as I can guess, error `SYSERR(pgsql)` is about user `pgsql` that have no permissions to some directory or file.

I also tried to do `grep pgsql /etc/mail/sendmail.cf` to find if there is any line containing `pgsql` (to see if there are any permissions restrictions), but I didn't find anything.

Comment: Are you using postgres to dynamically rewrite your sendmail.cf file somehow?  We really need more information about your environment to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a directory, you need execute as well as read permission in order to see files within the directory. So change the permissions to be

```
drwxr-xr-x
```

for /etc/mail